# Access to the SIP Diversion Header in RestComm RVD

Tags: restcomm

Is it possible to access to the SIP Diversion header in RestComm RVD using the feature explained in http://docs.telestax.com/accessing-sip-headers-from-an-rvd-application/ ?

Related Github issue by @otsakir: https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/issues/722

Comment: I see it's not possible, what I've posted is for Custom headers, not for all the SIP. I will fill an issue and update here

Comment: Rigth it's not possible right now. You may want to add an issue to specify through configuration the list of non custom headers to pass to the application in addition to customer headers.

Comment: Thanks @jeand. I will create the issue,  I'm currently working in the associated PR ;-)